# Flasgger / Swagger - apidocs works with localhost but not Openshift (You need to enable JavaScript to run this app)

Tags: javascript, swagger, openshift, traefik, flasgger

I am running a Python Flask server. A co-worker added Flasgger/Swagger support and I can successfully display the API using

```
http://localhost:5000/apidocs
```

Similarly, I can get the json version of the API

```
http://localhost:5000/api_documentation.json
  Python code configures that filename
```

That same code is deployed in an Openshift project and uses Traefik to route external requests to the Python Flask server

```
https://my-openshift-url-here/apidocs
  does not display the API
  only displays "Powered by Flasgger 0.9.5
https://my-openshift-url-here/api_documentation.json
  works same as the localhost request
```

Traefik keys off of the "apidocs" and "api_documentation.json" and routes it directly to the Python Flask server

```
        rule: PathPrefix(`/apidocs`)
        entryPoints:
          - web
        middlewares:
          - gzip
          - mysecurity-no-token
        service: my-python-server

      apidocumentation:
        rule: PathPrefix(`/api_documentation.json`)
        entryPoints:
          - web
        middlewares:
          - gzip
          - mysecurity-no-token
        service: my-python-server
```

What I see in my Chrome browser debugger (F12 - Network) for the swagger-ui-bundle.js response is "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app."

Why does this work in Chrome for the *localhost* version but not when accessing the server deployed on *Openshift*? Both are being accessed from the same Chrome window - just different tabs.

This is the Headers content of the apidocs request for the localhost version

```
    Request Method: GET
    Status Code: 200 OK
    Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:5000
    Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
    Content-Length: 3041
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Date: Thu, 19 Aug 2021 12:08:41 GMT
    Server: Werkzeug/2.0.1 Python/3.7.4
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Connection: keep-alive
    Host: localhost:5000
    Pragma: no-cache
    sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"
    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
    Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
    Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
    Sec-Fetch-Site: none
    Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36
```

This is the Headers content of the apidocs request for the Openshift version

```
    Request Method: GET
    Status Code: 200 OK
    Remote Address: 123.456.789.123:443 (obfuscated, of course)
    Referrer Policy: origin
    content-encoding: gzip
    content-length: 1264
    content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    date: Thu, 19 Aug 2021 12:08:59 GMT
    server: istio-envoy
    vary: Accept-Encoding
    x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 28
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Connection: keep-alive
    Host: my-openshift-server-url-here
    Pragma: no-cache
    sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"
    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
    Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
    Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
    Sec-Fetch-Site: none
    Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a Traefik routing issues. After the initial response to the /apidocs request, it was also making requests to /flasgger_static/foo. I had to add a route for flassgger_static in my Traefik routing table.

```
flassger:
  rule: PathPrefix(`/flasgger_static`)
  entryPoints:
    - web
  middlewares:
    - gzip
    - mysecurity-no-token
  service: my-python-server
```