# Accessing flasgger_static endpoints behind a reverse proxy?

Tags: python, flask, swagger, traefik, flasgger

Let's assume I have a Flask app exposing an endpoint `/login` and I expose this app behind a reverse proxy (traefik) using the prefix `my_app` (the proxy has to strip the prefix, however when I use the "try it out" function in swagger ui, it send the request to `/my_app/login` and my app doesn't know this route).

With this configuration, I can't reach the Swagger UI: if I set `url_prefix` to `my_app` in Flask configuration, the documentation will be exposed on `/my_app/apidocs` but the proxy will strip the first part of the path. I can "cheat" by accessing `/my_app/my_app/apidocs` but the page doesn't load (css, js etc...) because it will call `my_app/flasgger_static/swagger-ui-bundle.js` for example (and the my_app will be stripped by the proxy).

Is there any way to set the prefix only when accessing the ressources of the swagger ui?

To recap I would like to have the following endpoints exposed :

- `/login`
- `/apidocs`
- `/flassger_static/*`

but when I'm loading the ui, I would like to perform requests to `/my_app/flassger_static/*` (similarly to the try it out functionality where I can use `basePath`

Thanks

Comment: related article that helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68848715/flasgger-swagger-apidocs-works-with-localhost-but-not-openshift-you-need-to